# SQL Export using BCP Command

Tags: sql, ssms, bcp

I am trying to export using BCP command and this works when exporting locally but i need to export to a MAPPED network folder. I believe I would have to change this part of my code but can someone please explain what each section of this piece means? And how it should be modified since the folder is not local?

```
 EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
 GO
 RECONFIGURE;
 GO
 EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1;
 GO
 RECONFIGURE;
 GO

 DECLARE       @sqlCommand   VARCHAR(1000)

 DECLARE       @filePath     VARCHAR(100) 

 DECLARE       @fileName     VARCHAR(100)



 SET    @filePath = 'Y:\MD\'



 SET    @fileName = 'PracticeDictionary_' +

   + CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 112)+'.csv'



 SET  @sqlCommand =
 'bcp "EXEC proc_PracticeDictionary" queryout "' +

 @filePath + @fileName +

 ' " -S (local) -T -d IntergyLoad -c'




  EXEC   master..xp_cmdshell @sqlCommand

 GO


 EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
 GO
 RECONFIGURE;
 GO
 EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 0;
 GO
 RECONFIGURE;
 GO
```

Comment: `-S` is the server, to which you are passing `(local)`. So it's using the SQL Server on your local computer. `-T` means use integrated security (not a SQL login). `-d` is the database name `dbname` and `-c` means to use the char data type (as opposed to `-w` which would specify unicode/nchar). Here is a list of all the arguments: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: To answer your question, nothing needs changed with these arguments as far as I can tell. If you are exporting from the local server to a mapped drive you need to change the data_file argument, which would be the (missing) part of your command *before* the arguments you've listed here.

Comment: Thank you so much Jacob. This is all my code for the export maybe you can help me spot what my issue is. Im still confused as to why its not working. Permissions were given on the folder. The error is :  
    Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0]Unable to open BCP host data-file

Comment: Ok so your full BCP query looks like this: `bcp "EXEC proc_PracticeDictionary" queryout "Y:\MD\PracticeDictionary_20180531.csv " -S (local) -T -d IntergyLoad -c`

Comment: Check this thread: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/128894/125215 also I think maybe the space after .csv could be causing an issue with the file name.